# Find first day of the month previous to a random date with Pandas pd.DateOffset

Tags: python, pandas

I want to find the first day of a given month an average 90 days previous to a random date. For instance:

December 15 -- returns August 30
December 30 -- returns August 30
December 1st -- returns August 30

I know this can be done with `Pandas` pd.DateOffset:

```
print(pd.Timestamp("2019-12-15") - pd.DateOffset(days=90))
```

but then I'll get something like September 15th.

I know I can count minus 90 days, select the month, subtract 1 and then select last day of the obtained month, but I was wondering if this can be easily done in one line of code, efficiently.

Comment: If you want the first day of the month, why do you return the 30th?

Comment: Also, August has 31 days... But this might help: `pd.Timestamp('2019-12-15') - pd.offsets.MonthEnd(4)`, returns the last day of four months before your date... In this case, 2019-08-31. If you need exactly 90 days then the last day of the previous month, just subtract `pd.offsets.MonthEnd()` after subtracting 90 days... https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that the date in question is:

```
dat = pd.Timestamp('2019-12-15')
```

To compute the date 90 days before, run:

```
dat2 = dat - pd.DateOffset(days=90)
```

getting `2019-09-16`.

And finally, to get the start of this month, run:

```
dat2 - pd.offsets.MonthBegin(0)
```

getting `2019-09-01`.

To put tho whole thing short, run just:

```
dat - pd.DateOffset(days=90) - pd.offsets.MonthBegin(0)
```

A subtle difference becomes visible if you start from a date, which
turned 90 days back gives just the first day of a month. E.g.

```
dat = pd.Timestamp('2019-11-30')
dat2 = dat - pd.DateOffset(days=90)
```

gives `2019-09-01`.

Then `dat2 - pd.offsets.MonthBegin(0)` gives just **the same** date.

If you want in this case the start date of the **previous** month, run:

```
dat2 - pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1)
```

(note the argument changed to *1*), getting `2019-08-01`.

So choose the variant which suits your needs.